How To Display Discrete Points Per Day Without Stacking In Line Chart For Deneb
I'm trying to achieve something similar to what can be produce by native line chart from Power BI, but couldn't figure out what am i missing as i'm just starting out with Deneb pretty recently.
I'm trying to create a line chart with date as X-axis and value for Y-axis. The points on Y-axis must not stacked on top of each other each day like the top chart in the attached image below.
So far i've tried the code below but the points are stacking up on top of each other for that day.

    {
  "data": {
    "name": "dataset"
  },

  "layer": [

{"mark": {"type": "line", "point":true, 
 
"tooltip":true,
 "color":"#003668"},
"encoding": {



"x": {"field": "Date",
    "type": "temporal",
    "timeUnit": "datemonth",
    "axis": {"format":"%d/%m"},
    //"sort":["Point_ID","Date"],
    "scale":{"zero":false}

    
    },
"y":{"field":["Value"],
"type": "quantitative", 
"scale":{"zero":false},
"y2":{"field":["Point_ID"],
"type": "ordinal"}
}

}

}

  ]
}


The top chart in the image is my trial using Deneb, whereas the bottom chart is what i'm trying to achieve from native Power Bi line chart.
enter image description here
Please advice.
Thanks in advance.
Jay
